# Why such an output

Tags: c, pointers

I executed this code after compiling in codeblocks:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[]="HELLO";   
    int a=arr;    
    return printf("...%s ,%s\n",arr,&a+1);
}
```

I got this output:-
...HELLO,HELLO

when I changed `&a` to `a`,printf returned -1.
I am not able to sort out this address logic ,please help.
(A friend gave me this code and asked its explanation, and I am not able to find it). So I would like to know why..
Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Just Wanna know why this happens,as I am new to c language...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are telling `printf` to expect a string, but you are giving it the address of an `int` (`&a`).  This invokes **undefined behaviour**, so anything could happen.

[*In practice, what's probably happening is that the compiler places `a` directly below `arr` on the stack.  So `&a+1` ends up equal in value to `&arr`.  `printf` then reinterprets that address as a pointer-to-`char`, and so ends up printing `HELLO`.  If the compiler happened to arrange the stack differently, you'd observe different behaviour.*]

Comment: With that undefined behavior, it's not surprising that this resulted in a stack overflow. /pun

Comment: As what I think, if a is below arr,then adding a value to "a" will let it grow down in stack,which may not be arr.then how i am getting address of arr(plz correct me if wrong)

Comment: @Kislay: Adding 1 to a pointer always makes its address *increase*.